# get available memory in gb using single bash shell command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

following command returns available memory in kilobytes

`cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree | awk '{ print $2 }'`

can some one suggest single command to get the available memory in gb?

Comment: 'MemFree' is pretty useless. 'MemAvailable' generally makes more sense.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just a slight modification to your own magical incantation:

```
awk '/MemFree/ { printf "%.3f \n", $2/1024/1024 }' /proc/meminfo
```

P.S.: Dear OP, if you find yourself invoking grep & awk in one line you're most likely doing it wrong ;}  ... Same with invoking cat on a single file; that's hardly ever warranted.

Comment: That's much better than my answer and should be the accepted solution.

Comment: Thanks much! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 10):

Most simple is the following :

```
free -h
```

Following is the output Screenshot :

[image]

More details :

DESCRIPTION

```
   free - displays the total amount of free and used physical and swap mem‐
   ory in the system, as well as the buffers and caches used by  the  ker‐
   nel.  The  information  is  gathered by parsing /proc/meminfo. The dis‐
   played columns are:

   total  Total installed memory (MemTotal and SwapTotal in /proc/meminfo)
   used   Used memory (calculated as total - free - buffers - cache)

   free   Unused memory (MemFree and SwapFree in /proc/meminfo)

   shared Memory used (mostly) by tmpfs (Shmem in /proc/meminfo, available
          on kernels 2.6.32, displayed as zero if not available)

   buffers
          Memory used by kernel buffers (Buffers in /proc/meminfo)

   cache  Memory  used  by  the  page  cache and slabs (Cached and Slab in
          /proc/meminfo)

   buff/cache
          Sum of buffers and cache

   available
          Estimation of how much memory  is  available  for  starting  new
          applications,  without swapping. Unlike the data provided by the
          cache or free fields, this field takes into account  page  cache
          and also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be reclaimed
          due to items being in use (MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo, avail‐
          able on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+, otherwise the
          same as free)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
freemem_in_gb () { 
    read -r _ freemem _ <<< "$(grep --fixed-strings 'MemFree' /proc/meminfo)"
    bc <<< "scale=3;${freemem}/1024/1024"
}
```

Please notice that `scale=3` can be changed to some other value, for a better precision.
So, for example one could write a function that will take a precision argument, like so:

```
freemem_in_gb () { 
    prec=$1;
    read -r _ freemem _ <<< "$(grep --fixed-strings 'MemFree' /proc/meminfo)"
    bc <<< "scale=${prec:-3};${freemem}/1024/1024"
}
```

Which will take (or use 3 as a default value) and pass a precision argument to `bc`'s `scale` option

*Usage example:*

```
$ freemem_in_gb
5.524
$ freemem_in_gb 7
5.5115814
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for @Stephen P and @Etan Reisner for leaving a comment and improving this answer.
Code edited accordingly.

`grep`'s long option `--fixed-strings` is used purposely instead of `-F` or `fgrep` for explanatory reasons.

Comment: Using that redirection and regex grep is relatively expensive; OPs `cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree` and your `grep 'MemFree' < /proc/meminfo` can be done as `fgrep MemFree /proc/meminfo` using more efficient "fixed" (no regex) fgrep, no redirection, and fewer processes spawned.

Comment: @EtanReisner I don't think so. I wrote it by mistake. Thank you for commenting about it. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: It doesn't seem to hurt anything (it seems to work fine which strikes me as slightly odd but *shrug*) I was mostly wondering if there was some `bc` detail I wasn't familiar with at play.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein : just me personally, dividing by `4^10` feels cleaner than `/1024/1024`, but that's just me

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Go for it ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way:

```sh
expr $(sed -n '/^MemTotal:/ s/[^[:digit:]]//gp' /proc/meminfo) / 1024 / 1024
```

Also a bit shorter:

```sh
expr $(sed -n '/^MemTotal:/ s/[^0-9]//gp' /proc/meminfo) / 1024 / 1024
```

And if you like bc and precision that much:

```sh
bc <<< "scale=2; $(sed -n '/^MemTotal:/ s/[^[:digit:]]//gp' /proc/meminfo) / 1024 / 1024 "
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have python, you can do it this way:

To get total available memory:

```
python -c "import os;print(int(round(os.sysconf('SC_PAGE_SIZE') * os.sysconf('SC_PHYS_PAGES') / 1024.0**3)))"
```

In this example, I used `round` to round to the nearest GB. You can make it into a shell function like so:

```
get_mem(){
    MEM=$(python -c "import os;print(int(round(os.sysconf('SC_PAGE_SIZE') * os.sysconf('SC_PHYS_PAGES') / 1024.0**3)))")
    echo $MEM
}
```

To get free and used memory check out `psutil` [here](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/).

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I agree that dividing by 1024 should be more correct, I find on my various cloud and physical servers, this gives neater output:

`free -m | awk '/^Mem:/{printf("%.1fGb\n",$2/1000)}'`